My react-flow DAG looking funny after Dagre Layouting
I followed the example in the React-Flow docs and tried to stress test it by passing a fully connected neural-network-shaped DAG. The result is pictured in the figure below. It keeps spacing the nodes by half further as the layers increase.
Is there anything I can do? Any tweak to do or any argument to set?
Thank you!

